# Getting a 404 error during installation of R gtools package

Tags: r, installation

I'm getting a 404 error during the installation of the R gtools package:

```
> install.packages("gtools")
Installing package into ‘/Users/[...]/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtools_3.4.2.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gtools_3.4.2.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘gtools’ failed
```

Apparently, the latest version is not 3.4.2, but 3.5.0 (see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/index.html), so I'm wondering if this explains the error.  How do I install gtools (either 3.4.2 or 3.5.0 are fine)?  My current setup is OS X Yosemite (10.10.3), R version 3.1.3, RStudio 0.99.437.

Comment: have you tried install.packages("gtools", type="source") ? CRAN tends to maintain binaries only for the most up to date R version. So you can either update R, or use the compile from source option.

Comment: You probably should upgrade your R version first.

Comment: thanks! I upgraded my R version (to 3.2.0) and I've managed to install gtools.

Answer (score 0):

The version 3.5 should work with R 2.1 and higher. I would suggest that you download the package source `tar.gz` file available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/index.html) and attempt to install using the command below:

```
install.packages("path_to_your_file/gtools_3.5.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```